# Base64 to string of 1s and 0s convertor

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64, converters

I did some search for this question, but I can not find relevant answer. I am trying to convert some string form input() function to Base64 and from Base64 to raw string of 1s and 0s. My converter is working, but its output are not the raw bits, but something like this: *b'YWhvag=='*.
Unfortunately, I need string of 1s and 0s, because I want to send this data via "flickering" of LED.

Can you help me figure it out please? Thank you for any kind of help!

```
import base64

some_text = input()

base64_string = (base64.b64encode(some_text.encode("ascii")))

print(base64_string)
```

Comment: why are you `base64`encoding?

Comment: It is because in next steps of creating this VLC communication, I would like to convert images to bits as well. I found that images are better to convert to Base64 first, and after that to bits. I am completely novice in Python, so coverting strings and images to Base64 first and after that to bits, seems to be like a universal solution for me.

Comment: That is correct. So you want stream of 1's and 0's?

Comment: Yes, absolutely

Comment: How will you join the bits on the opposite side? Why do you have to do bit-level manipulation? It seems cumbersome?

Comment: I want to use photodiode on the other side. This photodiode will be connected to the RPi, same as the LED diode. Do you think that my idea is too coplicated?

Comment: No, it is fine as long as you construct the image from these bits properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood it corretly you want binary equivalent of string like `'hello'` to `['1101000', '1100101', '1101100', '1101100', '1101111']` each for `h e l l o`

```py
import base64

some_text = input('enter a string to be encoded(8 bit encoding): ')


def encode(text):
    base64_string = (base64.b64encode(text.encode("ascii")))
    return ''.join([bin(i)[2:].zfill(8) for i in base64_string])

def decode(binary_digit):
    b = str(binary_digit)
    c = ['0b'+b[i:i+8] for i in range(0,len(b), 8)]
    c = ''.join([chr(eval(i)) for i in c])
    return base64.b64decode(c).decode('ascii')

encoded_value = encode(some_text)
decoded_value = decode(encoded_value)

print(f'encoded value of {some_text} in 8 bit encoding is: {encoded_value}')
print(f'decoded value of {encoded_value} is: {decoded_value}')
```

Comment: Yes. I forgot to add. I want to convert images to stream 1's and 0's as well. This is why I am trying to convert this string to Base64 first. I should be more universal solution. I know that I can convert string pretty easily to bits, but I need to convert it to Base64 first.

Comment: Yes, but bit-level work seems cumbersome because on the other side you have to construct them again. Anyways, in your code you can change your print statement to `print(''.join([bin(i)[2:] for i in base64_string]))` to get the stream of bits

Comment: I do not know, if the mistake is in my head, but if I try to run this code, as you wrote before it does not work. If the input text is only a letter "a", it decodes it correctly as _YQ==_. However the result of decoding to binary seems not to be correct. It is _10110011010001111101111101_ which is  _s0ffQA==_ in online convertors to Base64.

Comment: @dejv_IT you are correct. That is happening due to the different size. It can be solved by making each encoded binary to 8 bits, Try `print(''.join([bin(i)[2:].zfill(8) for i in base64_string]))`

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Comment: @dejv_IT check the full code, I added all the methods

Comment: I think 7 bits are enough thoug since there are 127 characters are there

Comment: I really appriciate your help. Thank you very much!